# Can you get Facebook Insights for an open graph object INSTANCE, e.g., "Blowing in the Wind" vs. Songs?

Tags: facebook, object, analytics, facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights

As we all know the Facebook documentation is not the best.  It's internally inconsistent, ever changing, riddled with broken links and often out of date or just plain wrong.  I've searched and searched and I cannot seem to find the answer to a very simple question:  Can you get Insights data for an open graph object INSTANCE, e.g., "Blowing in the Wind" (instance) vs. Songs (type).

This seems like it should be an obvious use-case for Insights but it does not appear to be possible from what I can muster. [Facebook's Insights documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20121006074645/http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/insights/) says:

> Once you select an action filter, you have the option of further
> filtering by objects.

and they show this screenshot underneath this text which seems to show that you can filter Insights by open graph object TYPE not by individual object INSTANCE. So, which is it?!  They are very loosey-goosey with their terminology which makes understanding the documentation *that* much harder...

[image: this screenshot]
<sub>(source: [facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/og_insights_select_actions_2.png))</sub>

Through the Graph API it appears that the only Insights data you can get is at the Application, Domain or Page (Facebook page not web page) level as stated in [their docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20140123021057/https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/):

> **API Reference › Graph API › Insights**:
> An object containing statistics about applications, pages, and domains.

...and the same seems true of [FQL](https://web.archive.org/web/20151015045538/https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights):

> **API Reference › FQL › insights**:
> An FQL table containing statistics about Applications, Pages, and Domains with 30 or more connections.

So, my guess is that it's not possible, but, the need to get analytics on an open-graph object instance seems so obvious that I feel I must be missing something here. I mean wouldn't Spotify want to know which songs in their catalog are being shared/seen more often in Facebook?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you find an answer for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the interface or API supports object instance level insights, only object-type / action type.

If it did work, a call to /OBJECT_ID/insights with the app access token is the most logical place for them to be

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't mean to call you out here, but, it may sound like that's what I'm doing.  I saw on your profile that you work at Facebook and have actually written some of their APIs.  Is there anyway you could give a more definitive answer to this question?

Comment: I know the insights interface definitely does not support this - i'm not 100% sure if the API has any other data not exposed in the interface, but i don't think it does

Comment: @Igy is this possible in the graph API now given this "application_opengraph_story_impressions*" and others in the docs at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/ ?